# Updating model to Dom using Qt?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom, model-view-controller

I'm using model/view of Qt4.8 to developing an application. It can do such things:

1. load xml and display. XML looks like this:

   ```
   <Config>
       <Symbol>
           <Car_symbol>
               <SymbolSize>12</SymbolSize>
               <SymbolPath>e:/car.jpg</SymbolPath>
           </Car_symbol>
           <Ship_symbol>
               <SymbolSize>10</SymbolSize>
               <SymbolPath>e:/ship.jpg</SymbolPath>            
           </Ship_symbol>
       </Symbol>
       <Network>
           <Server>192.168.0.2</Server>
           <Port>5555</Port>
           <Local>192.168.0.1</Local>
       </Network>
       <Mode> 
           <SingleMode>1</SingleMode>
       </Mode>
   </Config>
   ```

   QDomDocument reads xml and set data to model. TreeView set model and Delegate such like this:

   ```
   class MyModel : public QAbtractItemModel
   {
   public:

      //data();
      //flags();
      //headerData();
      //index();
      //parent();
      //rowCount();
      //columnCount();
      void setData(QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
      void setupModelData(QDomDocument& doc);   //set doc's tag to model's item

   private:
       TreeItem item;
   }

   QDomDocument domDoc("xmlDoc");   //global object
   QFile file("config.xml");
   //...open  file correctly
   docDoc.setContent(file);


   MyModel model;
   model.setModelData(docDoc);

   QTreeview treeview;
   treeview->setModel(&model);
   MyDelegate delegate;
   treeview->setItemDelegate(&delegate);
   ```
2. Using delegate to edit model's data.

   ```
   //click on delegate
   delegate.setModelData(editor, model, index);   

   //index got from delegate, value is input value, role is EditRole     
   model.setData(index, value, role);     

   //item is a member of model, it saves the value
   item.setData(value);
   ```
3. The changed data of model could be restored in XML(or QDomDocument).

And after step 2, the data of model is changed. But how could I changed the data of QDomDocument or updating data to Dom?

Comment: I’d suggest to read the document into your own domain-specific data structure (with QXmlStreamReader preferably, but QDom would also work) and serialize that data structure back to XML using QXmlStreamWriter/QDomDocument.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld You mean I should create a data structure to store the data from model, then put it back to Dom? But model already has the data, should it be a easier way to putting data to Dom?